# p5js button.mousePressed calls function + arguments?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

probably silly question but is this possible or not in p5js?

```
function setup() {
   myButton.mousePressed(toggleVideo(1)); //This toggleVideo works well without argument
}

function toggleVideo(v) {
    blablabla[v].loop();
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The reason yours doesn’t work is because mousePressed takes in the variable that references the function, namely, toggleVideo. By putting the parentheses you are actually calling the function which executes when reached in setup

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
mousePressed(function() { toggleVideo(1);});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest JS, you can write the following:

```
function setup() {
 myButton.mousePressed(() => {
    toggleVideo(1)
 });
}

function toggleVideo(v) {
  blablabla[v].loop();
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the previous answer.